# error when using 'Kerning' option in graphicsmagick

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'am using graphicsmagick to annotate an image. I've been able to apply font,pointsize etc,

but when I applied kerning, got the error as

> *TypeError: Object #gm has no method 'kerning'*

Kerning is supported by [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#text_operators) but not graphicsmagick?

Is there any way to use kerning in graphicsmagick?

Or is there any alternative to Kerning in Graphimagick to have spacing between text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The -kerning option appeared in ImageMagick in December 2008, long after the ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick fork happened.  It isn't available in GraphicsMagick.

Comment: This is a really annoying feature to have missing :(